# Why are my FactoryGirl defines not working correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I've defined a factory called admin_user but I am getting an error when I try to use it:

factories/user_factory.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email "example_user@example"
    password "password"
  end

  factory :admin_user do
    email "admin_user@example.com"
    password "admin_password"
  end
end
```

authentication_steps.rb:

```
Given /^I have a valid admin account$/ do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:admin_user)
end
```

I am getting the following error when I run that step:

```
uninitialized constant AdminUser (NameError)
```

Is there some syntax I'm not following correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the class of `:user_admin`:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :admin_user, :class => User do
    email "admin_user@example.com"
    password "admin_password"
  end
end
```

Explanations:

When you use `factory :admin_user do`, FactoryGirl looks automatically for the *AdminUser* class, which doesn't exist.
Thus, you have to tell it which class to use by adding `:class => User`.

Comment: the class specified is User, though...  :admin_user is just the name of the factory.

Comment: I added explanations in my answer. Hope you better understand.